# Modify BigQuery Operator to pass explicitly JobId argument AirFlow operators

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Im currently using the `Big-query Operator` [see here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py). Im required to explicitly send a user generated `JobId` argument.

Im aware that this operator creates by default its own generated JobId, however i'm interested in overriding this behaviour, unfortunately this operator does not accept JobId as an argument.

I tried to pass such an argument through the `api_resource_configs` and got the following message (Notice that my JobId argument was ignored):

```
[2019-02-12 14:01:09,402] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: /usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py:2159: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to BigQueryOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
[2019-02-12 14:01:09,403] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: *args: ()
[2019-02-12 14:01:09,403] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: **kwargs: {'api_resource_configs': {'jobReference': {'jobId': 'goodfornothing'}}}
[2019-02-12 14:01:09,403] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   category=PendingDeprecationWarninghere any version of this operator that gets that argument? can i some how modify the operator to accept this argument?
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Which version of the Airflow are you using? The api_resource_configs was introduced since V1.10.2.

Comment: @RyanTheCoder thanks, i'm using version 10.1 (cloud composer does not supports 10.2 yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since api_resource_configs was introduced in Airflow v1.10.2 ([code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py)), and Cloud Composer does not support this version yet. You may consider copying the latest BigQueryOperator's code, as your own custom operator, to your project.